# How to make a object create another object

Tags: python

As in the title how do I go about creating a object which creates another object? The object is simply supposed to replicate itself so like I call on this class to replicate itself the objects don't have to be different just that it creates another one of itself in like a endless loop. The grey goo example is basically what I want.

Comment: This object that is being created... where does it go?

Comment: Please specify better what exactly you mean. What do you want to achive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class foo(object):
    def make_object(self):
        return []

f = foo()
myobject = f.make_object()
```

This object creates another object (an empty list) and returns it.

But I have a feeling this is not what you intended. You need to specify more in your question and explain what specifically you are having trouble with. The snippet above is a trivial example that shows how easy it is to satisfy your question (it could have actually been shorter).

**UPDATE**

Here is the example slightly modified, just to show you how you can create an object of the same type

```
class foo(object):
    def make_object(self):
        return foo()

f = foo()
myobject = f.make_object()
```

Comment: I want it to create an object like say I define a class of something before hand like a class for a Person well I want a class that allows me to duplicate that person sort of like its replicating almost endlessly.

Comment: @asdfaea sure you can do that - an object can instantiate an object of its same type inside one of its methods. At that point you just have to deal with the bookkeeping of copying over data to "replicate" the object once it is created, then return it.